# Grid Layout in .NET MAUI doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, .net, layout, maui

I wanted to do specific layout for android screen. At the top I want to have two information labes (Box1 and Box2). Below them I want to have field which take rest of the screen (Box3). At the absolute bottom I want to have field with control buttons. I tried a lot of layout, but noone worked.
I'm using the latest release candidate version of .NET MAUI on windows 11 with latest Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview in Version 17.3.0 Preview 1.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Calendar.MainPage">
         
<ScrollView
    BackgroundColor="Violet">
    <Grid
        RowDefinitions="50, 50, *, 50">
        <Label
            Grid.Row="0"
            Text="Box1"
            BackgroundColor="Red" />
        <Label
            Grid.Row="1"
            Text="Box2"
            BackgroundColor="Green" />
        <Label
            Grid.Row="2"
            Text="Box3"
            BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
        <Label
            Grid.Row="3"
            Text="Box4"
            BackgroundColor="Aqua" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

And result is a bit different

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrwgb.png)

Can anyone help me and tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *take rest of the screen* ... it rather takes rest of the parent's content size ... which in the  scope of `ScrollView` is infinity

Comment: If you remove the `ScrollView` it should work as you expect. Do you need it to be scrollable?

Comment: Wow, so fast response. And I got rid the unnecessary elements and it works now. Thank you. I should find it myself. It is logical. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `ScrollView` it should work as you expect.

Comment: It seems the Grid doesn't work well inside a ScrollView.  Ridiculous.  Worked in XF.